# C#: How to find class that implements IRepo<T1, T2>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic interface: `IRepo<T1, T2>`.
And I have several classes that implement this interface:

```
class UserRepo:       IRepo<UserEntity, long>
class AdminUserRepo:  IRepo<UserEntity, long>
class OrderRepo:      IRepo<Order, Guid>
```

How can I scan the assembly to find:

- find `UserRepo` and `AdminUserRepo` which implement `IRepo<UserEntity, long>`(`User` and `long` are known at runtime)
- find all the repo classes which implement `IRepo<T1, T2>`(T1 and T2 are unknown)

Comment: Are all your classes in the same assembly?

Comment: If we posited the existence of a further class - `class OtherOrderRepo : OrderRepo` (I.e. it doesn't *directly* implement the interface, but inherits from a class that does) should that be included in your results or not?

Comment: @acostela yes, they are in the same assembly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, the ones not directly implement the interface should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To find types implementing a closed generic interface

  ```
  assembly.GetTypes().Where(type =>
      typeof(IRepo<UserEntity, long>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
  ```
- To find types implementing an open generic interface

  ```
  assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.GetInterfaces()
      .Any(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepo<,>)))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this piece of code with Linq I hope it helps.

```
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```